# Regex is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written an regx pattern for validating assembly version format "1.0.0.0". It is working in online regx validator but when I am writing the regx in my javascript it is not working because extra / are appending after converting the regx string with the below code. What is the way out for this?

```
 var regx = new RegExp("(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d)");
 var value = regx.test(value);
```

Comment: Add a backslash before every backslash.

Comment: Use `/.../` instead of `new RegExp`.

Comment: Remember that back-slashes in strings needs to be escaped with another back-slash.

Comment: @Sweeper I have tried with this /(\d+\.)(\d +\.)(\d +\.)(\d)/ but not working

Comment: Change your regexp to `/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/`. Because i assume you just want only the digits, not digit plus dot.

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `var value = regx.test(value);`? You're using the variable before declaring it?

Comment: try this. `var regex = /(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d)/;
regex.test("1.0.0.0");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var regx = /(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d)/g;
var result = regx.test(value); // return boolean
```

Comment: Don't use `/g` unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: use /g for All matches. I know

Comment: No, that's not what `/g` does.

Comment: g = global. All matches (don't return after first match). I see it in regex101.com

and my answer not correct?

Answer (score 1):

If the format is fixed as `X.X.X.X` - that is 4 digits separated by `-`, then use

```
var regex = /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/;
regex.test("1.1.1.1"); //true
```

However, if the **assembly version** could be `x.x` or `x.x.x`, etc - That is digits separated by `-`  and in any number, then use

```
var regex = /^\d+(\.\d+)+$/;
regex.test("1.1.1.1"); //true
regex.test("1.1"); //true
regex.test("1.1.1"); //true
```

If the version could be a single digit as well, then use * instead of + after the final `(\.\d+)` as

```
var regex = /^\d+(\.\d+)$/;
regex.test("1.1.1.1"); //true
regex.test("1.1"); //true
regex.test("1.1.1"); //true
regex.test("1"); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to choose one of the following forms:

```
 var regx = new RegExp("(\\d+\\.)(\\d+\\.)(\\d+\\.)(\\d)");
 var regx = /(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d)/;
```

There's a difference in javascript between creating a regex with the `//` syntax versus `new RegExp`.

With `new RegExp('regex here')` like you've done, the regex class takes in a **string** as the input. This is important when it comes to backslashes. For a normal javascript string, the backslash `\` character is a control character. If you want to have that character appear in your string, you need to escape it. So for every backslash that you want to show up in your regexp, you need to have 2x as many - one set so it gets passed through your string. For example: `console.log('hello \\ backslashes');` prints out as `hello \ backslashes`.

The other option is to use the shorthand syntax of `//` When making a literal regex, the backslash is treated as a normal character. However! now you need to escape the forward slash.